# Use-case for debug static runtime?

Tags: visual-c++

Visual C++ has debug and release and dynamic and static runtime libraries. What's the use case for the static debug library?
AFAIK you're not supposed to distribute the debug runtime library and on your own machine the DLLs are available anyway.

Comment: The use case for static library *may* be to avoid DLL Hell. You ship Release build, but use Debug to... debug (go figure). I think I didn't understant the question.

Comment: I think you didn't. Since you don't ship the debug build, there appears to be no need for the static debug runtime. Hence my question: what is it used for?

Comment: Let me know if I understood. See my answer, and don't hesitate to ask for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have chosen a CRT model for your Release builds, **you want** the same model for your debug builds, in order to minimize the differences between Debug and Release behaviors.

If you use the dynamic CRT for your Debug build and the static CRT for your Release build, you may experience bugs triggered only in Release build, and not reproducible in Debug build. That's very bad.

Example: You use `malloc` in a DLL and use `free` with the pointer in the EXE using the DLL.

Debug dynamic CRT: no problem.
Release static CRT: weird things happen.

If you had used the Debug static CRT, you'd have seen the problem sooner.

EDIT: [Potential Errors Passing CRT Objects Across DLL Boundaries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235460.aspx)

> Each copy of the CRT library has a separate and distinct state. As
>   such, CRT objects such as file handles, environment variables, and
>   locales are only valid for the copy of the CRT where these objects are
>   allocated or set.
>  When a DLL and its users use different copies of the
>   CRT library, you cannot pass these CRT objects across the DLL boundary
>   and expect them to be picked up correctly on the other side. Also,
>   because each copy of the CRT library has its own heap manager,
>   allocating memory in one CRT library and passing the pointer across a
>   DLL boundary to be freed by a different copy of the CRT library is a
>   potential cause for heap corruption.
>  If you design your DLL so that it
>   passes CRT objects across the boundary or allocates memory and expects
>   it to be freed outside the DLL, you restrict the DLL users to use the
>   same copy of the CRT library as the DLL. The DLL and its users use the
>   same copy of the CRT library only if both are linked with the same
>   version of the CRT DLL. [...]

Comment: Using dynamic CRT doesn't guaranteed the DLL is build using the same CRT as the application, does it? Have you got a reference for your explanation?

Comment: @XTF My answer is an answer to the question "Use-case for debug static runtime". Use case is: use the same CRT model in Debug and Release builds.